# Problem on Time and Distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

A train of length of $5km$ is running at a speed of $\frac{2.5km}{h}$ with some uniform stoppages every hour. For how long did the train stop in each hour if the train crossed a platform of half its length in $4$ hours and $20$ minutes?

(a) 20 min

(b) 30 min

(c) 35 min

(d) 40 min

How to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the correct answer 20 min?!

Comment: i don't know the right answer. got this question online. how did u get 20 min?

Comment: I'll answer it and u check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity of the train = $\frac{2.5km}{h}$

Length of the train = $l = 5km$

Distance traveled = $l + \frac{l}{2} = 7.5km$

Time spent to travel that distance = $\frac{7.5}{2.5} = 3$hours

3 hours = 3 stops that costs it a delay of 1 hours and 20 minutes, hence every stop costs it a delay of $\frac{80m}{3} = 26.67$ minutes on each stop.

But any letter contains that option, so I assumed that it made a stop before it starts to move, therefore, $4$ stops costs it a delay of $80$ minutes, and each stop was $20$ minutes long!